# Can I run a one-liner using Meteor Shell?

Tags: meteor

As I develop useful one-liners, it'd be handy to be able to run `meteor shell`, passing it the one-liner, and expecting that it will exit when done. Some syntax such as this, perhaps ?

```
meteor shell -e 'Meteor.users.remove({})'
```

Is this a feature request, or does it already exist already ?

Supplemental: I picture adding several of these scripts to `package.json` so they can be shared by all developers on the project.

Comment: Hi Dean! I asked [the same question](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/UScD0WroZkI/AsC9VGpGqMYJ) the other day.

Comment: This package author should be mentioned, perhaps they have something to say about doing this kind of thing too: https://atmospherejs.com/practicalmeteor/mcli

Answer (score 8):

Here's an [Expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) program for scripting the Meteor shell. You can either run a separate file or run a command directly. Usage:

```
./mshell -f runThisFile.js
./mshell -e 'console.log("foo")'
```

Here's the code (License: MIT). Save to a file (`mshell`, or whatever you choose) and make executable:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect --
set timeout 3
spawn meteor shell
expect "> "
set firstArg [lindex $argv 0]
set secondArg [lindex $argv 1]
if { $firstArg == "-f" } {
  send [exec cat $secondArg]
  send "\n"
} elseif { $firstArg == "-e" } {
  send "$secondArg\n"
}
expect "true"
send "\x04"
expect "Shell exiting...\n"
```

On Ubuntu I ran `sudo apt-get install expect` to install Expect prior to running this program.

Clearly we'd rather running scripts or one-liners were built into `meteor shell`, so let's just consider this a proof-of-concept.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to expect, and demoing a solution. Definitely an upvote, maybe an accepted if I get it to work and don't hear anything else in a day or two :)

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you!